# Tap on notification to open app destination with Navigation component, incorrect destination

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to open a specific destination in my navigation graph from a tap on notification. I created Pending Intent as follows-

```
//this code in service to create notification       
OccasionViewerArgs.Builder builderArg = new OccasionViewerArgs.Builder();
builderArg.setPrimaryKey(2);
builderArg.setOccasionClickType("Birthday");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.dashboard_navigation)
    .setDestination(R.id.occasionViewer)
    .setArguments(builderArg.build().toBundle())
    .createPendingIntent();
```

**Issue:**

When I am tapping on notification, I was expecting to navigate to my "occasionViewer" fragment, which is the same fragment, setup as destination `R.id.occasionViewer`, but I am getting navigate to start destination fragment of nav graph which is "dashboardFragment".

I try to change the destination to one of other destination in same graph `R.id.addBirthdayFragment` as follows -

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.dashboard_navigation)
    .setDestination(R.id.addBirthdayFragment)
    //.setArguments(builderArg.build().toBundle())
    .createPendingIntent();
```

and then It's working as expected, means upon notification tap I am getting navigate to addBirthdayFragment.

Could you please look into this and let me know what i have done wrong here, any suggestion or help would make my day.

**Here is the nav_graph (R.navigation.dashboard_navigation)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/dashboard_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="buzz.anusmarak.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label=""
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_addBirthdayFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addBirthdayFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_occasionViewer"
            app:destination="@id/occasionViewer"/>
    </fragment>
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addBirthdayFragment"
        android:name="buzz.anusmarak.ui.birthday.AddBirthdayFragment"
        android:label="Add Birthday"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_birthday" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addBirthdayFragment_to_dashboardFragment"
            app:destination="@id/dashboardFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/dashboardFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addBirthdayFragment_to_occasionViewer"
            app:destination="@id/occasionViewer"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/dashboardFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/occasionViewer"
        android:name="buzz.anusmarak.ui.dashboard.occasion_viewer.OccasionViewer"
        android:label=""
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_occasion_viewer" >
        <argument
            android:name="primaryKey"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="-1" />
        <argument
            android:name="occasionClickType"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="default" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_occasionViewer_to_dashboardFragment"
            app:destination="@id/dashboardFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Thank you for your effort and time in advance.

**Edit 1**

Observer As follows

```
private LiveData<Occasion> occasionLiveData;

        occasionLiveData = AppRoomDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext().getApplicationContext())
                .occasionDao().findOccasionByKey(primaryKey);

        occasionLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Occasion>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Occasion occasion) {
                if (occasion != null) {
                    setupValues(occasion);
                }
            }
        });
```

Method `setupValues(occasion)`, where I am using Occasion to update the different values.

I am using the observer in onActivityCreated().

**Edit 2**

OccasionViewer

```
public class OccasionViewer extends Fragment implements DatePickerFragment.DatePickerDialogListener
        , MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "OccasionViewer";

    private int primaryKey;
    private String occasionClickType;
    private ImageView isImportantImg, makeCall;
    private CircularImageView personImg;
    private LiveData<Occasion> occasionLiveData;
    .....

    public OccasionViewer() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            primaryKey = OccasionViewerArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getPrimaryKey();
            occasionClickType = OccasionViewerArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getOccasionClickType();
            Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move);
            setSharedElementEnterTransition(sharedElementEnterTransition);
            postponeEnterTransition();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        occasionLiveData.removeObservers(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_occasion_viewer, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        occasionLiveData = AppRoomDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext().getApplicationContext())
                .occasionDao().findOccasionByKey(primaryKey);

        occasionLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Occasion>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Occasion occasion) {
                if (occasion != null) {
                    setupValues(occasion);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        personImg = view.findViewById(R.id.person_img);
        isImportantImg = view.findViewById(R.id.is_important_img);

        toolbar.setTransitionName(occasionClickType+primaryKey+"cardView");
        personImg.setTransitionName(occasionClickType+primaryKey+"imageView");
        isImportantImg.setTransitionName(occasionClickType+primaryKey+"importantView");

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(collapsingToolbarLayout, toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        .................

    }

    private void setupValues(Occasion occasion) {
        //using occasion to setup values
    }

    // further method for setup different fields
}
```

**Edit 3 (Some Observation)**

My DashboardFragment has a recycle view, on item click it navigate to OccasionViewer, but when tapping on notification, which does take me to DashboardFragment, and then i click on recycle view item, it come up with this error:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
07-30 10:56:57.695 16143-16143/buzz.anusmarak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: buzz.anusmarak, PID: 16143
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination buzz.anusmarak:id/action_dashboardFragment_to_occasionViewer cannot be found from the current destination Destination(buzz.anusmarak:id/occasionViewer) label= class=buzz.anusmarak.ui.dashboard.occasion_viewer.OccasionViewer
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:931)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1128)
        at buzz.anusmarak.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onUpcomingOccasionClick(DashboardFragment.java:387)
```

**Adding PSR**

Find the PSR for the issue here..

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-3yuQU-4YPprZHk5cUGoq20Ck82y3omT/view?usp=sharing

**Edit 4 (Solved by AdrianK)**

I was calling `startPostponedEnterTransition();` as follows

```
private void setupValues(Occasion occasion) {
    matchingOccasion = occasion;
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(matchingOccasion.getPersonName());
    String personImageID = matchingOccasion.getPersonImage();
    if (!personImageID.isEmpty()) {

    File filepath = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File file = new File(filepath + "/" + personImageID + ".jpeg");
    Picasso.with(requireContext()).load(file)
        .into(personImg, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // startPostponedEnterTransition();
    }
    .......
```

Issue is fixed by following change -

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ......
    startPostponedEnterTransition();
    ......
```

Again I would like to thank **AdrianK** to take time and look into my code. Cheers.. !!

Comment: I went through again https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link still not able to resolve it

Comment: Are you using the latest Navigation 2.3.0 release? If so, you should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828) with a project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for your time and reply. I am using Navigation 2.3.0 release. I try to reproduce the issue by creating a test project but its working fine, I am still not able to figure out why I am facing the issue in my actual project. Only difference between test and actual project is, data coming from Room Database based on the parameter passed.

Comment: Can you include the code for `OccasionViewer`? Is your fragment calling your `action_occationViewer_to_dashboardFragment` action anywhere (such as in an `observe`)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake there is no action as action_occationViewer_to_dashboardFragment, i am letting navigation take card of back navigation. I added the observer on question and will be providing the OccasionViewer as well

Comment: Ah, well you certainly have that action in your graph. I was trying to understand if you **are** deep linking to `OccasionViewer` successfully, but then immediately navigating back to your `DashboardFragment` from some code that is in your `OccasionViewer`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did remove the action_occationViewer_to_dashboardFragment from graph, got no error but still the same issue,  I updated OccasionViewer's code, its not full code as the code is long and I know your time is precious.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did found on observation on Edit 3 and provided PSR as well, hope you will look into it.

Comment: are you sure you are calling `startPostponedEnterTransition()` in `OccasionViewer`? That could be one reason why the fragment doesnt show up, but the navController thinks you are already there

Comment: @AdrianK you are a real lifesaver. You resolved the issue with a single statement. I am editing the question with the resolution. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you as well for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved in **Edit 4.** by AdrianK